# Spring Framework + Thymeleaf: How to call a ModelAndView method every few seconds/Scheduled task

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Framework with the Twitter's API, and I have a method to get tweets related with hashtags.

This method is called from the view using a th:action with a th:object and th:field from where I get the hashtags for the query.

In the controller, I have a ModelAndView method, which receives the "hashtags" and gets tweets and returns to the same view but now with a List filled with these tweets.

Is there any way that when I press the button the method call itself every x seconds until I press another button or I call another method? (To filter the current list of tweets for example or to do a new search).

I know there is an annotation @Scheduled but it needs a non-parameter method, and also I need to repeat a method at certain part of the execution, not from the start of it.

I know it's a basic idea, but anyway, i'm going to leave a picture with what I have programmed (top), and what I'm trying to get (bottom)
[image: Visual explanation of the problem]

This is the view:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="#" th:action="@{/twittercontrolador/buscartuits}" th:object="${textoplano}" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <b>Hashtags/Menciones:</b> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Max 5 - #asdf / @nick" th:field="*{texto}" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">Buscar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And here the controller (Just a @controller, spring controller page)

```
 @PostMapping(value="/buscartuits")
        public ModelAndView obtenerTuits(@ModelAttribute("textoplano") TextoEnPlano texto){
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("vistaPrincipal");
            String resultadoBusqueda = this.textoBusqueda(texto.getTexto());
            List<Tweet> listaTuits = twitter.searchOperations().search(resultadoBusqueda).getTweets();
            listaPropia = new ArrayList<ObjetoTuit>();
            int contAux = this.listaDe5Elementos.getNumElementos(); 

            for(int i=0; i<listaTuits.size();i++){

                ...
            }

            mav.addObject("listaobjetostuits", listaPropia);
            return mav;
        }
```

I've tried using this:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ but this seems not to be right for me

Answer (score 0):

Its just Java code in the end. Don't you want it connected to the front end though? If yes use setTimeout in the client html. If you want to do something in the back end only, can use spring batch or a java thread (not recommended but will work if you do it correcrly and there are not too many other threads being started in your code).

What code have you tried ? When you say Controller you mean a REST API call? Or is it a JSP or spring controller page?

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html we dont use this on a controller -> usually at the service/ facade layer of the back end. Like for a background job to be done.

If your doing it from the HTML can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout Javascript code

You can use cron to all a URL every x time units.

You can use a HTTP library to call your URL programmatically, that can have a authenticaiton (login) step and then call you Controller steps. Then use scheduler to make it happen at some repeated way. Spring has a HTTP library, or can use Apache Http Components, or OkHttp or java.net.URL depending on complexity of the page and what works in your case. I have used all.

Can even use Jmeter - via the API or programmatically.

You can make a selenium to programmatically open a browser and do actions like logon, open a page, fill & submit a form, on the system where the selenium code runs. Then use scheduler in this app.

First you need to define your problem and what exactly you have tried better.

And do more research using the alternatives I have listed.

Comment: Just edited the comment, I've used : https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ but as I said it seems not to be good for me. Also I need to do some logic from the back, so I think hte javascript solution may not work for me

Comment: Unless you specify why its not right we cant help you. I added a few more alternatives. Cron, http library, Jmeter, selenium are all ways to do this from within or outside your own app